# How to find out link names to remove links from "My Account" page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

My first aim was removing some links from account dashboard. I've searched for it and found some solutions. Applied this: [Remove navigation links from My Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887664/remove-navigation-links-from-my-account)

It works like a charm, no problems.

The thing is how to find out proper link name?

For example, I need to remove "My Tags" link. What's the name for that? Tried some variations and "tags" worked.

But cannot find out any solution for "My Applications".

Is there a list of this kinda link names?

Thanks,

Comment: You can also use this free and easy 'plug and play' extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-navigation-menu.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not the best way but it works:

open the file /app/design/frontend/your/theme/template/customer/account/navigation.php

insert this line:

```
<?php unset($_links['OAuth Customer Tokens']); ?>
```

after this line:

```
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
```

so here the result:

```
<div class="block-content">
<ul>
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
<?php unset($_links['OAuth Customer Tokens']); ?>
<?php $_index = 1; ?>
<?php $_count = count($_links); ?>
```

In this page there is a "for" cycle for the array $_links i just remove the object for "my application" link.

Cheers

Comment: you mean navigation.phtml not .php

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IDE such as Eclipse PHP, and search for a specfic text. i am sure you will get your search results. After that you just need to delete/ modify the text.

Hope,this trick helps you.

Comment: It's not working that way. Those are dynamic generated links.

Thanks anyway,

Comment: As you may have seen in the linked post, people wrote some codes to remove those links :)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I hope this helps. You can find some good information regarding the link names and how to remove them here: http://www.kerstner.at/en/2014/08/remove-customer-account-navigation-links-in-magento/

The specific names for My Account links are:

- My Account: account
- Account Edit: account_edit
- Address Book: address_book
- My Orders: orders
- My Tags: tags
- My Wishlist: wishlist
- My Applications: OAuth Customer Tokens
- Recurring Profiles: recurring_profiles
- Billing Agreements: billing_agreements
- My Downloadable Products: downloadable_products
- My Reviews: reviews
- My Invitations: invitations
- Newsletter Subscriptions: newsletter
- Logout: logout

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove tags & my downloadable product just add these line:

> unset($_links['tags']);
>
> unset($_links['downloadable_products']);

bye

Comment: sorry it was my fault on paste the code...  insert these line inside of php tag of course...   :)   bye

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using an extension. [Front end links Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/MagePsycho/extension/7905/frontend_links_manager) extension is used to turn on/off the frontend links(top links, footer links, customer).

Obvious benefit is that no core files need to be edited using this solution.

However as stated this doesnt remove the My Applications link. In order to remove the My Applications using this app, you need to do 3 things.

1. Modify app\design\frontend[your theme]e\layout\xmllinks.xml and add
   `<action method="removeLinkByName" ifconfig="xmllinks/customer_navigation/my_applications"><name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name></action>`
   under customer_account
2. Modify app\code\local\MagePsycho\Xmllinks\etc\system.xml and add to below my_wishlist

   ```
   <label>My Applications</label>

   <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>

   <source_model>xmllinks/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>

   <sort_order>105</sort_order>

   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>

   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>

   <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

   </my_applications>
   ```
3. Finally add a record to the core_config_data table in your database. Just copy the my_wishlist record and insert the new record and change my_wishlist to my_applications

   Clear cache, log out, log in and disable.