# Dynamically add links to 'my account navigation' in magento

Tags: templates, magento, layout, block

I'm creating a Magento Extension and want to be programatically add links to the 'My account' navigation. I've read the following thread ([Magento - How to add/remove links on my account navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977824/magento-how-to-add-remove-links-on-my-account-navigation)) and the sites it references, but they only talk about adding a link statically.

By adding the following to a layout file in my module I can get a new link to appear in the customer account navigation.

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="mymodule">
            <name>modulename</name>
            <path>mymodule/</path>
            <label>New link</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

How can I make it so that this links appearance depends on the results of a method call to one of my extensions models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use event-observer functionality of magento
The event you have to use it "controller_action_layout_load_before"
In your module's config.xml

```
<controller_action_layout_load_before>
    <observers>
        <uniquename>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Package_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>customlink</method>
        </uniquename>
    </observers>
</controller_action_layout_load_before>
```

and in the corresponding observer.php use the following code

```
public function customlink(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
    $update->addHandle('customer_new_handle');
}
```

and in local.xml write

```
<customer_new_handle>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="mymodule">
            <name>modulename</name>
            <path>mymodule/</path>
            <label>New link</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_new_handle>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've tried it and it does work. However it appears to be really inefficient as it will call my method (which access the database) for every page load, irrespective of whether the visitor is even logged in. Is this really the best/only way of achieving this?

Comment: well i get your point ... if you want to avoid executing the whole function if the customer is not logged in you can check if the customer's session is set or not inisde..
public function customlink(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
}
and i can't say this is the best way... if you get any share it over here

Answer (score 2):

I've come across this same need and this is the best way to achieve it I've found.

1) Create a new Block file that extends the Magento Account Navigation Block, with the following code.

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Addlink extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation {
    public function addLinkToUserNav() {
        if (your logic here) {
            $this->addLink(
                    "your label",
                    "your url",
                    "your title"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

2) In your extension config file **config.xml**, add the following code (respecting your existent XML data structure):

```
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        ....
        <blocks>
            ...
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <account_navigation>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Addlink</account_navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

3) In your extension XML layout file, add the following code (respecting your existent XML data structure):

```
<layout>
    ...
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLinkToUserNav"></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

And this is it. This will provide you the ability to dynamically add/remove account navigation links.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use Magento's ifconfig attribute as explained [here](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-layout-xml-conditions.html)