# Magento Custom Extension To show my account links

Tags: magento, navigation, ticket-system

I have created a Magento extension, to integrate OST Ticket into magenta. This is working great however the only issue I'm having is to display the "My Account" Links.

On my account dashboard I have the following links:

- Account Dashboard
- Support Tickets
- Account Information
- Address Book
- My Orders
- Billing Agreements
- Recurring Profiles
- My Product Reviews
- My Wishlist
- My Applications
- Newsletter Subscriptions
- My Downloadable Products

When I include the block into my extension using the following code:

```
<support_index_index>
       <reference name="content">
            <block type="support/list"  name="support_list" template="support/list.phtml" />
       </reference>
       <reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="support/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        </block>
        <remove name="tags_popular"/>
        <remove name="leftnav" />

    </reference>


  </support_index_index>
```

I only get 4 links:

- Account Dashboard
- Support Tickets
- Account Information
- Address Book

Can someone please explain to me why this would happen and how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look @ /app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/review.xml

```
<customer_account>
    <!-- Mage_Review -->
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="review"><name>reviews</name><path>review/customer</path><label>My Product Reviews</label></action>
    </reference>

</customer_account>
```

See [Magento - How to add/remove links on my account navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977824/magento-how-to-add-remove-links-on-my-account-navigation)

Comment: Oh i see, so they are actually all manually added just hidden in other xml files. I assumed that the links would be collected dynamically some way but clearly not. Thanks for clearing that up for me.