# Display my account navigation links

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created custom page and added that link to my account page. But if I click on that link side bar disappears. How can I show my account navigation sidebar in my custom module page?

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977824/magento-how-to-add-remove-links-on-my-account-navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use update handle e.g.

```
<layout>
<cevent_index_index>    --- your custom module handle in layout.xml
    <update handle="customer_account"/>  -- check customer.xml
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">   ---- block in customer_account handle
        <block type="cevent/cevent" name="cevent" template="cevent/cevent.phtml"/>
    </reference>    
</cevent_index_index>
</layout>
```