# How to add Logout URL under every section of My Account Page?

Tags: magento

I have a requirement that the logout url must be visible only in *My Account* bottom for every section of it like on  "Account Information","Address Book", "My Orders"  similar for all.

[image: Please See the sample Image]
How to do this?

Where should I write

```
action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
```

in My `customer.xml` file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can remove the block 'customer_logged_in' in customer.xml and then you can add/make a block in customer.xml like this.

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="my.account.wrapper" translate="label">
                <label>My Account Wrapper</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>my-account</value></action>
                <block type="core/template" name="logout_link" template="customer/logout_link.phtml"/>
            </block>
 </reference>
```

And the content of the logout_link.phtml would be something like,

```
<?php
$loggedIn = $this->helper("customer")->isLoggedIn();
if($loggedIn == 1){
    echo "<a href=\"".Mage::getBaseUrl()."customer/account/logout/\" >LOGOUT</a>";
}else{
    echo "<a href=\"".Mage::getBaseUrl()."customer/account/\" >LOGIN</a>";
}?>
```

....

Comment: I followed your code. It shows "You have logged out and will be redirected to our homepage in 5 seconds." But it is automatically redirecting me to home page from my account page

Comment: Oh! You have to set the different template means you need to create other template where you can print log out link logic. 'customer/logout.phtml' is just for an example. logout.phtml will do what you mentioned in your comment

Comment: I edited this answer to fix issue with self-closing <a/> tag.  The fix was two characters and StackOverflow requires edits to be at least six characters, so I added those four dots at the end to get around that silly rule.  Is there a better way?

Comment: The accepted answer is a poor solution. See here for a better method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1978313/2929617 and here for a method to remove links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4343095/2929617

Answer (score 9):

It's better to use these URL's:

```
Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl()
Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl()
```

It uses the customer helper instead of a hard coded URL.