# Magento customer account navigation on 1column page layout

Tags: magento, navigation, account

I want to make my customer account page into 1column page layout then move the customer_account_navigation from left to top of the content. Any idea/approach on how to easily do this? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TO move the navigation menu, you need to edit the `customer.xml` layout file of your theme and 
and inside the tag `<customer_account>` move this section.

```
<block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
   <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
   <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
   <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
</block>
```

Remove if from inside the tag `<reference name="left">` to `<reference name="content">`.

Also in order to change the template from `2columns-left` to `1column`, change inside the same tag `<customer_account>`, this:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

TO this:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

You may need to make some css changes after that to make the navigation menu fit in your theme.

Comment: Thanks mate for this. Working like a charm! I just wonder how to have this on my local.xml instead of changing customer.xml?

Answer (score 2):

Open `app\design\frontend\YOUR_THEME_TEMPLATE\default\layout\customer.xml` file.
    In that `customer_account` chnage

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
```

to

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
```

For Account Links on top See:- [Magento - How to add/remove links on my account navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977824/magento-how-to-add-remove-links-on-my-account-navigation)