# Magento call account information phtml block

Tags: javascript, magento, account, php

We are making an other page on our website with the account information layout.
 We wanted to call this block but we end up just having the h3 title: Account information.

We used this:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="customer/account/dashboard.phtml"}}
```

Result:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Q17INWi.jpg]

What we want:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/RBCWKQj.png]

**Nevermind the categories!**

Is there something we are doing wrong, well, obviously we are doing something wrong.

Any more information needed? Feel free to ask!

Comment: i have the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to set the page template for this action in layout xml.

Like following:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

And you put your block code to in `<reference name="content"> ..... </reference>` block.

Comment: Do I need to put this code in the layout.xml code or in the back-end?
(Layout Update XML)

Comment: I have created the page using the admin panel, not for my well being but for my colleagues ;)

Comment: I will put another answer.

Comment: Thank you! I will appreciate that!

Comment: please select Layout to "2 columns with left bar" in Design tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65975/discussion-between-james-and-sj03rs).

Answer (score 0):

When you are outputting the {{block...}} declaration you are doing it in the content of the page, what you want to do is use the XML layout to insert your menu into the "left" block a.k.a the left sidebar

In Design > Page Layout > Layout choose 2 column left sidebar, then paste this block in the XML section (remove the unnecessary links if you want):

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="downloadable"><name>downloadable_products</name><path>downloadable/customer/products</path><label>My Downloadable Products</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="newsletter"><name>newsletter</name><path>newsletter/manage/</path><label>Newsletter Subscriptions</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="oauth"> <name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name> <path>oauth/customer_token</path> <label>My Applications</label> </action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="review"><name>reviews</name><path>review/customer</path><label>My Product Reviews</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="tag"><name>tags</name><path>tag/customer/</path><label>My Tags</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"><name>wishlist</name><path>wishlist/</path><label>My Wishlist</label></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

This answer is a partial reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977824/magento-how-to-add-remove-links-on-my-account-navigation) post with a bit of research by me on the extra blocks by magento

There are also limitations of this implementation as you cannot make this page secure. As far as I know you will need to create a custom module for that, this [article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_create_customer_page) by @AlanStorm should help you out

Comment: He want the data in the content of the page because we(me and him we are working on it together) want to have tabpages on top and then account info, catalog, and some other tabs